# Prove the following statement using axioms of real field

Tags: real-analysis

a) if $x+y = x+z$ , then $y=z$

b) if $xy=xz$ and $x$ not equal to $0$ , then $y=z$

c) $-(-x)=x$

d) if $x$ not equal to $0$ and $xy=x$ , then $y=1$

e) $(x^{-1})^{-1} =x$

I didn't understand what my lecturer teach about this topic ! So i really need some help !
Here are my answer for a , b ,c and d . Can anyone help me check ?

a) (-x) + x + y = (-x)+x+z

[(-x) + x ] + y = [ (-x) + x ] + z

0 + y = 0 + z

y=z

b) (1/x)(xy) = (1/x)(xz)

[(1/x).x] y = [ (1/x).z]

1.y = 1.z

y=z

c) -(-x) = x

-(-x) + (-x) = 0

add x to both side :

x + [ -(-x) + (-x) ]= x+ 0

x + 0 = [ x + (-x)] + [-(-x)]

x= 0+ -(-x)

=-(-x)

d) let xy=x , and x ≠ 0

∃ z ∈ R ∈ xz = zx =1

1=zx

1= z(xy)

1=(zx)y

1=1.y

1=y

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the axioms to prove the statements. Sometimes it can be a bit tricky, but you should try it ourself, otherwise you don't learn how to use it.

For example the first can be done the following way:
On axiom states that you can add $0$ to each number. So,
$$
y=y+0
$$
Next, each element has an additive inverse, so you can use $x+(-x)=0$ and you get
$$
y+0=y+(x+(-x))
$$
Use the associative property to get
$$
y+(x+(-x))=(y+x)+(-x)
$$
Now, you can use the equation $y+x=z+x$ and you get
$$
(y+x)+(-x)=(z+x)+(-x)
$$
And use the same steps as above to get $z$ at the end.

Comment: i know i have to try but i really don't understand the whole topic ! So i hope to learn from examples to make myself clear .